# Extract date from a field

Tags: mysql

I am trying to extract the date from a field that contains other information as well. My aim is to put the date in a separate column. The field is as follows:

```
      sample_documents/2013/01/08/326/
```

I have tried the following without success:

```
  SELECT sf.file_path ->> 'yyyy-mm-dd' as 'Date'
```

Comment: Your fields looks always like : sample_documents/2013/01/08/326/ ? Can you add some more entries ?

Answer (score 0):

If all your values for that field have the same format/pattern, you can go with :

```
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(sf.file_path, "/", -5), "/", 3)
FROM Your_Table;
```

Reference: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index

Answer (score 0):

Here is another method where `SUBSTRING_INDEX` gets you the string starting from the 5th slash counting backwards (thus "/", -5) and from that output, `MID` gets you the date portion which has 10 characters (thus 1,10).

Again, consistency of the pattern and format is crucial.

```
SELECT MID(SUBSTRING_INDEX(`sf.file_path`, "/", -5), 1, 10) as `Date`
FROM Your_Table;
```